# Display animated gif in ImageIcon proxy with java swing

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, imageicon, animated

I used to write that this

```
JLabel label=new JLable(URL);
frame.getContentPane().add(label);
```

and it works with animated gif image

however , when I want use a imageProxy to load the gif form the internet
it doesn't work.

my imageProxy is this

```
public class ImageProxy implements Icon{
ImageIcon imageIcon;
URL imageURL;
Thread retrievalThread;
boolean retrieving =false;
public ImageProxy(URL url){
    imageURL = url;
}

public int getIconHeight() {skip}
public int getIconWidth() {skip}

@Override
public void paintIcon(final Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
    System.out.println("paint");
    if(imageIcon !=null){
        imageIcon.paintIcon(c, g, x, y);
    }else{
        g.drawString("Loading image", x+10, y+80);
        if(!retrieving){
            retrieving =true;
            retrievalThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    try{
                        imageIcon = new ImageIcon(imageURL);
                        c.repaint();
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            retrievalThread.start();
        }
    }
}
```

}

it can success to load the image but it won't auto to refresh it image
I have to chage to image by zoom the frame,
every time i zoom it chage one picture

I read the document ,
it said that , in other to display a gif i need to setImageObsever 
i tried , doesn't work. and the imageIcon normal work with no proxy print null by getImageObserver

I also tried to read the souce code but i did not really understand.

Pleas help me ,thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of the problem is probably in the implementation of `ImageObserver` interface by `JLabel`:

```
public boolean imageUpdate(Image img, int infoflags,
               int x, int y, int w, int h) {
    // Don't use getDisabledIcon, will trigger creation of icon if icon
    // not set.
if (!isShowing() ||
        !SwingUtilities.doesIconReferenceImage(getIcon(), img) &&
        !SwingUtilities.doesIconReferenceImage(disabledIcon, img)) {

    return false;
}
return super.imageUpdate(img, infoflags, x, y, w, h);
}
```

Here is the code for `SwingUtilities.doesIconReferenceImage`:

```
static boolean doesIconReferenceImage(Icon icon, Image image) {
Image iconImage = (icon != null && (icon instanceof ImageIcon)) ?
                   ((ImageIcon)icon).getImage() : null;
return (iconImage == image);
}
```

As you can see, if the icon is not instance of `ImageIcon` the result of `imageUpdate()` will be `false`, without even calling into super's implementation which is actually responsible to call `repaint()` on `JLabel` to refresh the new frame of the animated icon. Also, returning `false` means we are no longer interested in updates.

You may extend `JLabel` to overcome this constraint. Here is a very simple extension of `JLabel` that overrides `imageUpdate()`. The actual code for this implementation of `imageUpdate` is taken from `Component.imageUpdate()`, just `isInc` and `incRate` are constants for simplicity:

```
public static class CustomLabel extends JLabel {
    private static final boolean isInc = true;
    private static final int incRate = 100;

    public CustomLabel(Icon image) {
        super(image);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean imageUpdate(Image img, int infoflags, int x, int y,
            int w, int h) {
        int rate = -1;
        if ((infoflags & (FRAMEBITS | ALLBITS)) != 0) {
            rate = 0;
        } else if ((infoflags & SOMEBITS) != 0) {
            if (isInc) {
                rate = incRate;
                if (rate < 0) {
                    rate = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        if (rate >= 0) {
            repaint(rate, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }
        return (infoflags & (ALLBITS | ABORT)) == 0;
    }
}
```

You may plug into `imageUpdate()` to add the functionality of displaying *"Loading image"* string while image is still loading.

I wonder what is the real reason behind the implementation of proxy for `ImageIcon`. If you need synchronous image loading you can use `ImageIO` API.